# Initialize object array with properties from another array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, initialization

I have an object with some string properties:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I need to initialize an array of this object from a string array. Right now I'm doing this:

```
MyObject[] FromString(string[] s)
{
    var o = new List<MusicFile>();

    foreach (var item in s)
    {
        MyObject o = new MyObject {MyProperty = s};

        o.Add(new MyObject { MyProperty = s });
    }

    return o.ToArray();
}
```

Is there a better shorter way to do it? Maybe in one line with a constructor?

Comment: [codereview stack](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be more suitable to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrayOfObjects = arrayOfStrings.Select(s => new MyObject{ MyProperty = s}).ToArray();
```